# Pass windows credentials from Web Api to SharePoint Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, sharepoint

I have a web api that is being called by an angular web app via Windows Authentication. I need to use the credentials that are passed via the Windows Authentication to get into the share point api.

The following is an example of the code that I currently have. (Note that the ... symbolizes where I have omitted some code, there are a few more usings and I don't believe that the code of what is being done on Sharepoint is needed for this.)

```cs
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Web;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Net;

...

 public static List<SPDocument> GetSPDocumentsById(int itemId)
 {  
    using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://...")
    {                     
        //This I believe is giving me the IIS user Identity, and not the Windows
        //credentials that the user is logging into the API with. 
        context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        ...

    }
 }
```

My issue is very similar to the one in this question: [IIS Application Pool Identity to use Logged On User Windows Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45030331/2793683), but the steps to resolve this issue do not fix my issue. Within the controller if I check the value of `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

I get the user name that I am expecting, but if I check `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;`, I get the IIS User account. If the `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;` call returned the logged in users windows account, this would fix my issue.

Comment: If you're using Web API, you can get the current Windows Authenticated user by using the User property of the Controller. You can then get User.Identity etc.

Comment: @Jon I have this in a separate service from my controller, so I would like to avoid passing the data from the controller if at all possible.

Comment: To clarify, this code is in a class library that the web api is calling into.

Comment: You'll need to pass the Windows credentials into the class library then (from the Web API). Assuming your Web API uses Windows Authentication.

Comment: I would think that the class library being part of the web api project should have access to the user. I think that my problem is that the defaultNetworkCredentials is returning something other than the logged in user.

Comment: In the controller, you can access the User property. Can't you just pass this reference to your library, or is it a closed library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was a Kerbos double hop issue as explained in this article (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop/), to fix this we simply moved the api over to the same server as the other resource it was trying to hit.